# Formula to return count of duplicate dates based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets, I have a column of dates in A and checkboxes in column B (Redeemed).

1. I want a formula to count, for each unique date, how many times it appears in the column where the following two conditions are also met:

   1. The date is in the same month as a lookup date in `D2`
   2. The checkbox in the date's row is `TRUE` (ticked)
2. I want to use that count to calculate:

   1. In `E3`, the sum of the count
   2. In `E4`, the number of times the count includes the number `2`
   3. In `E5`, the number of times it includes the number `3`
   4. In `E6`, the number of times it includes a number `>=3`

### Example Showing Results `E3:E6`

[image]

In the example above,

1. `E4=11` because there are 11 dates in the month of October, 2023 (lookup month) that also have their "Redeemed" checkbox ticked.
2. `E5=1` because there is only one date, `10/2/2023`, that appears exactly twice, is in the lookup month, and has the "Redeemed" checkbox ticked.
3. `E6=1`, only `10/5/2023` appears exactly 3 times and meets the other conditions
4. `E7=2`, `10/5/2023` and `10/10/2023` appear 3 or more times and meet the other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

###### [Demo Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHOLZCE0CG7ZjyE9gYAtmbuivAYq8WFAWPsx51UEPW0/edit)

Includes the following tabs:

1. [ReadMe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHOLZCE0CG7ZjyE9gYAtmbuivAYq8WFAWPsx51UEPW0/edit#gid=953131243)
2. [Query_Approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHOLZCE0CG7ZjyE9gYAtmbuivAYq8WFAWPsx51UEPW0/edit#gid=272672337)
3. [Arrayformula_Approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHOLZCE0CG7ZjyE9gYAtmbuivAYq8WFAWPsx51UEPW0/edit#gid=453828198)
4. [Dynamic_Months_Approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHOLZCE0CG7ZjyE9gYAtmbuivAYq8WFAWPsx51UEPW0/edit#gid=2100307022)

### Query Approach in `D4`

- [Demo Spreadsheet: Query_Approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHOLZCE0CG7ZjyE9gYAtmbuivAYq8WFAWPsx51UEPW0/edit#gid=272672337)

```
=LET(
   nums, QUERY(
     A2:B, "Select COUNT(A) where B=TRUE
     and MONTH(A)+1 contains '"&MONTH(E2)&"'
     and YEAR(A) contains '"&YEAR(E2)&"'
     Group by A"),
 { "TTL Redeemed", SUM(nums);
   "2 Redeemed",  COUNTIF(nums,2);
   "3 Redeemed",  COUNTIF(nums,3);
   "3+ Redeemed", COUNTIF(nums,">=3") })
```

### Arrayformula Approach in `D4`

- [Demo Spreadsheet: Arrayformula_Approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHOLZCE0CG7ZjyE9gYAtmbuivAYq8WFAWPsx51UEPW0/edit#gid=453828198)

```
=LET(dates,A2:A, lkup,D2, 
   nums,MAP(UNIQUE(dates), LAMBDA(d,
     ARRAYFORMULA(
       SUM((d-DAY(d)=lkup-DAY(lkup))*
         (dates=d)*(OFFSET(dates,0,1)))))),
 { "TTL Redeemed", SUM(nums);
   "2 Redeemed",  COUNTIF(nums,2);
   "3 Redeemed",  COUNTIF(nums,3);
   "3+ Redeemed", COUNTIF(nums,">=3") })
```

### Dynamically Generate Lookup Months

- [Demo Spreadsheet: Dynamic_Months_Approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHOLZCE0CG7ZjyE9gYAtmbuivAYq8WFAWPsx51UEPW0/edit#gid=2100307022)

```
=LET(rng,A3:A, 
  uniq, UNIQUE(TOCOL(rng,1)),
  months, SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
     EOMONTH(rng*OFFSET(rng,0,1),-1))+1)), 
  calc, LAMBDA(c, MAP(uniq, LAMBDA(u,
     ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((EOMONTH(u, -1)+1=c)*
          (rng=u)*(OFFSET(rng, 0, 1))))))),
  BYROW(TOCOL(months,3), LAMBDA(m, LET(
     count,calc(m), 
     IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(1/(1/
      { m, SUM(count),  COUNTIF(count, 2), 
        COUNTIF(count, 3),
        COUNTIF(count, ">=3") })), "-")))))
```

- This approach returns the results in a row instead of a column.
- It will automatically list all months for which there is a redemption, and adds any new months as redemptions are added in `A2:A`.
- Months are sorted ascending but that can be switched by modifying the SORT in the variable `months`

---

## Screenshots

<sub>**Lookup Date**   *( custom date format; day is irrelevant )*</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Query Approach**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Arrayformula Approach**</sub> 
[image]

<sub>**Dynamically Generate Lookup Months**</sub>
[image]